Is it correct to put a section separator (double thin lines) in the middle of a measure?
I like to denote different sections of a piece by double thin bar lines. I use Lilypond, and there is a command there, \section that produces such lines.
Question: if a new section of a piece starts not from the beginning of a measure, is it fine to use this command?
I attach an image where double lines are inside a measure.


It looks confusing because what you call a section separator is a double bar line, which functions the same as a bar line and makes it look like two bars of 2/4 with no key signature change. I would advise against it. I would put the double bar after 4 eighth notes, which seem like an anacrusis. It is common to have an anacrusis before a double bar line and it is understood that it is part of the subsequent phrase.

OK, thank you for a new word to learn (anacrusis). I have never heard this term before, TBH. Indeed, this piece has a lot of phrases that starts with 4 eights in the previous measure.

After some googling on anacrusis and section separation, it seems that it is a relatively common question :-)

Yes, it's fine to do that — the meaning is clear. In some settings a dotted bar line is used, but that's more for clarifying rhythmic or metric divisions in free time, large meters (say, 19/4), or frequently varying meters. For the situation in the question, the double, thin bar lines are best.

If I can find an example of this in the standard literature, I'll post it, but if anyone knows of one, please let me know.

I feel like it's common enough when it's a repeat...

I would say go for it just to be a tiny bit creative and anarchistic ;) It's human communication after all, not a programming language for machines.

There are examples in Schubert 6 Moment Musicaux, no.2 in Ab. The movement is in 9/8, in A-B1-A-B2-A form; the B2 section has a sixteenth-note anacrusis and the A section has a dotted-quarter-note anacrusis, and in each case the section divider (double bar line) is placed before the anacrusis, at least in the first couple of editions I checked. I’m sure there are plenty more in Schubert’s piano works and similar classical writing; this was just the first I thought of. That said, I think the other alternative is generally preferred today.

The Schubert example from my previous comment: scores at IMSLP, image excerpt.

Actually, dotted/dashed bar lines are also used for phrase subdivisions in some contexts. I've some books of Bach chorales that use that, for example: https://i.sstatic.net/M69RPaZp.png

That descending line of eighths in octaves looks like it could be an anacrusis, and if so the double bar section separation might be better after the descending line.

Thank you, this is what I have decided to do (to put the double-bar separator between the measures).
